# WPF define ConverterCulture/Language in resources

Tags: wpf, xaml, globalization

I would like default culture/language to be defined as resource in order to provide consistent displaying of selected labels. It seems, however it is not possible to define neither `Language`(XMLLanguage) nor `ConverterCulture`(CultureInfor) resource, it does not seem to be possible to use a `string` resource neither:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, 
           Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={StaticResource DateFormat},
           ConverterCulture={StaticResource DefaultCulture},
           Language={StaticResource DefaultLang}/>
//....
<Grid.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="DefaultCutureString">en-GB</sys:String>
    <win:XmlLanguage xmlns:win="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Markup;assembly=PresentationFramework" x:Key="DefaultLang">en-GB</win:XmlLanguage>
    <g:CultureInfo xmlns:g="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib" x:Key="DefaultCuture">
        <x:Arguments>
            <sys:String>en-GB</sys:String>
        </x:Arguments>
    </g:CultureInfo>
</Grid.Resources>
```

How can I define and apply Culture/Language using Resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XmlLanguage` and `CultureInfo` have no default parameterless constructors which means you cannot instantiate them in XAML.

But you could create the resources programmatically and then add them to `Grid.Resources` (just give the `Grid` and `x:Name` of "grid" or similar in the XAML markup to be able to identify it in the code):

```
grid.Resources["DefaultLang"] = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-GB");
grid.Resources["DefaultCuture"] = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
```